# VB.NET Controls Not Visible

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I am trying to see all the labels in `Me.Controls` and when I use:

```
For Each Control As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    MsgBox(Control.Name.ToString)
Next
```

it only shows the labels that have NOT been renamed.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Re-reading your question now.  Your question doesn't mention anything in regards to your title "Controls Not Visible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, your code looks right, unless you have labels inside other container controls like Panels and GroupBoxes.  In which case, you would need to loop through those containers, too.

Here is an example:

```
Dim allContainers As New Stack(Of Control)
allContainers.Push(Me)
While allContainers.Count > 0
  For Each item As Control In allContainers.Pop.Controls
    If item.Controls.Count > 0 Then
      allContainers.Push(item)
    End If
    If TypeOf item Is Label Then
      MessageBox.Show("Label.Name = " + item.Name)
    End If
  Next
End While
```

Comment: Good catch, that is exactly what the problem was!  Thanks!